# Process cannot access file because its used by another process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dispose, fluentftp

So I'm getting exception "Process cannot access file because its used by another process.

The exception will show when i call this particular method:

```
public async static Task<bool> DownloadFileFromFTP(string PathToFile, string AppName)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => {
       if (File.Exists("settings.xml"))
       {
           XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
           FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
           Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);

           try
           {
               FtpClient client = new FtpClient(info.HDSynologyIP);
               string a = info.FtpPassword;
               string FTPPassword = EncryDecryptor.Decrypt(a);
               client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(info.FtpUsername, FTPPassword);
               client.Connect();

               bool finish = client.DownloadFile(@info.Downloads + "\\" + AppName, PathToFile, FtpLocalExists.Overwrite, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry);
               if (finish == true)
               {
                   client.Disconnect();
                   read.Close();
                   return true;
               }
               else
               {
                   client.Disconnect();
                   read.Close();
                   return false;
               }

           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
               read.Close();
           }
           read.Close();
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Missing settings.xml file");
           return false;
       }
       return false;
   });
}
```

And call it in another class like this:

```
await General_Functions.DownloadFileFromFTP("Ultra_Script/Basic_SW/Adobe_Reader.exe", "Adobe_Reader.exe");
```

It wasn't asynchronous before but i had to remake it into asynchronous method. But i think I'm closing reader and client correctly. Can it be problem of async method? Because i don't had this problem before i made it asynchronous.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

*Note, I am using `FluentFTP` from https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP .*

Comment: Are you aware of using `using` to call `Dispose` for you?

Comment: I can't see a huge benefit of using `await` there, given you are spinning up a new `Task` anyway. What makes you think it is useful here?

Comment: What is the exception' stack trace?

Comment: Is `Adobe_Reader.exe` already running? Did you check Task Manager?

Comment: @mjwills Btw im learning how async method works so im trying to do everything in async just for purpose of learning. But doesnt it make app more responsible when doing tasks?

No Adobe_Reader is not running at all there is no code who will open it, just download it from ftp repozitary

Comment: yes i checked. nothing there

Comment: @Renat, here is the whole exception trac: https://i.imgur.com/yVk4ONr.png

Comment: Any luck on the [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

use using to terminate the file reader process

```
using(FileStream read = new FileStream("settings.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{ 
    // your code here.....
}
```

Comment: Didnt help :-(.